# Error in nextjs app: Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist\client\components\static-generation-async-storage.external.js'

Tags: node.js, next.js, deployment, next.js13, next.js14

**Error:** Cannot find module 'next/dist\client\components\static-generation-async-storage.external.js'

I have this problem in my nextjs app, I am using typescript and tailwind, I am trying to deploy my app to a shared server which uses cpanel, apache and ubuntu, this error appears when visiting the domain and it only shows me an error 500 with nextjs style.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "socialty-media",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.9",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.7",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.12",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

i use a custom server for the deploy this is my server.js:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = '0.0.0.0'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
 
      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

I tried to reinstall my dependencies and I still have the same problem, the version of Node I use is ^18 since in order to upload my website it is necessary to create an app in Nodejs on the server

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this issue today after upgrading nextjs version `13.4.9` to `14.0.4`.
You can try to downgrade nextjs version if possible.

*Otherwise:*

Replace this line from the file "\node_modules\next\dist\build\handle-externals.js".

**From:**

```js
return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist")}`
```

**To:**

```js
return `commonjs ${localRes.replace(/.*?next[/\\]dist/, "next/dist").replace(/\\/g, "/")}`
```

Then, build and upload to your shared hosting.

*This is a temporary solution I found from [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58244)*

Comment: I tried various versions from 13.2 to 14.0.4, downgrading didnt help me
I deploy on node App engine.
The solution helped

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with next 14. After trying and error I found that the issue was due to the fact that I was running `next build` in windows system and deploy to a linux system which handles path differently; use of different systems can lead to the issue.

What I did was to build my project in Linux system like [GitHub codespace](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/overview) or alike and deploy the resulting .next to cPanel, Et voilà.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new prestart script worked for me:

```json
"prestart": "next build"
```